# how to use a variable value in anchor's href

Tags: php

```
<a href="uploads/templates'.$row[0].'/index.php?id=<?php echo $row[0];?>" 
   class="btn btn-warning">
     View
</a>
```

above is the button and in this button i want to give a path in which folder named templates should be like templates1 ,templates2, templates3. So the numeric value is a variable and 0to be attached with templates so that the folder can open and the index file can be run..so can any one help me with this

Comment: fix your code example plz. there is a function for adding code to your question - use it. and maybe show more of your code as well, cause i have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: what are you asking please clear

Comment: sorry for that.. i m new on this site.and i find the solution..but thak you..i will be careful from the next time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="uploads/templates/<?php echo $row[0]; ?>/index.php?id=<?php echo  
$row[0];?>" class="btn btn-warning">
View</a>
OR
<?php
echo '<a href="uploads/templates/'.$row[0].'/index.php?id='.$row[0].'" 
class="btn btn-warning">
View</a>';
?>
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by a bit more of a comment as to what it's doing.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="uploads/templates<?php echo $row[0];?>/index.php?id=<?php echo $row[0];?>" class="btn btn-warning">
 View
</a>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing PHP code inside HTML, you need to wrap your code in `<?php ?>`.
Your code should be:

```
<a href="uploads/templates<?php echo $row[0]; ?>/index.php?id=<?php echo $row[0];?>" class="btn btn-warning">
     View
</a>
```